# Python regex vs Regex101

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Input string:

> I0419 01:52:16.606123   136 TrainerInternal.cpp:181]  Pass=15 Batch=74 samples=3670 AvgCost=263.331 Eval: classification_error_evaluator=0.970178 I0419 01:52:16.815407   136 Tester.cpp:115]  Test samples=458 cost=203.737 Eval: classification_error_evaluator=0.934446

Pattern:

> Pass=([0-9]+).*classification_error_evaluator=(0.[0-9]+).*classification_error_evaluator=(0.[0-9]+)

Desired output:

```
(15, 0.970178, 0.934446)
```

And on Regex101(https://regex101.com/r/Hwxsib/1), it seems like I'm capturing the right pattern.

But in Python, it didn't match the groups and it caught nothing:

```
import re

x = "I0419 01:52:16.606123   136 TrainerInternal.cpp:181]  Pass=15 Batch=74 samples=3670 AvgCost=263.331 Eval: classification_error_evaluator=0.970178 I0419 01:52:16.815407   136 Tester.cpp:115]  Test samples=458 cost=203.737 Eval: classification_error_evaluator=0.934446"

pattern = "Pass=([0-9]+).*classification_error_evaluator=(0\.[0-9]+).*classification_error_evaluator=(0\.[0-9]+)"

re.match(pattern, x)
```

**What is the difference between the regex101 settings as compared to Python `re` package? Or are they the same?** Do they have different flags or settings/something?

**Why isn't the pattern matching in Python?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `re.search`, `re.match` only will return a match if it appears at the beginning of your string

regex101 also shows you the code it uses: https://regex101.com/r/Hwxsib/1/codegen?language=python

From the regex101 code, here's what it is doing (copied and edited for brevity):

```
import re

regex = r"..."

test_str = "..."

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

...
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `re.search`. `match` will only return if the match is at the start of the string!

```
import re

x = "I0419 01:52:16.606123   136 TrainerInternal.cpp:181]  Pass=15 Batch=74 samples=3670 AvgCost=263.331 Eval: classification_error_evaluator=0.970178 I0419 01:52:16.815407   136 Tester.cpp:115]  Test samples=458 cost=203.737 Eval: classification_error_evaluator=0.934446"

pattern = r'Pass=([0-9]+).*classification_error_evaluator=(0\.[0-9]+).*classification_error_evaluator=(0\.[0-9]+)'

print re.search(pattern, x).groups(1)
```